# how to collect form values from a pop up window

Tags: javascript

I would like to have the user click a button on the main document and this opens a new window pop-up which contains a form. I would like the user to input their data into the form and then close the window and be able to collect the user provided data from the new window. So far I can generate the pop-up window but can't collect the user supplied values from the form. Here is the code so far:

```
var OpenWindow = window.open("", "newwin", "height=250,width=250,toolbar=no,scrollbars=" + scroll + ",menubar=no");
                OpenWindow.document.write('<B><br>' + '<font color="blue" size = "4" >' +
                        "Please complete the following: " + '</B></font>');
                OpenWindow.document.write("<FORM>Image height(px)  <input type='text' name='image_height' id='image_height' value='800' size='5'></input><br>Image width(px)  <input type='text' name='image_width' id='image_width' value='800' size='5'></input><INPUT TYPE='BUTTON' VALUE='Submit' id='submit'  onClick='window.close()'></FORM>");

                var realWidth   = OpenWindow.document.getElementById('image_height').value;
                var realHeight  = OpenWindow.document.getElementById('image_width').value;
```

Comment: Why not create a "Visualized" popup window that is actually on the same page. (Just a centered div) as popup's are really discouraged now, and will possibly be blocked by popup blockers.

Comment: I would totally agree with @DeanMeehan . But if you would really do this, then you need some kind of callback method which reloads the other window with the variables. Be sure to save all the data which was entered in this window before. But this is not 2015, it's more 2000.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use overlay's to solve this problem, as it would be easier to do what you want (your form elements will be accessible as you would do if the form was in the same page).